# Best Practice: Protected or Private Methods by Default and Test-Driven Development

Tags: oop, unit-testing, tdd, design-principles

#### Similar Questions

- [When do you write a private method, versus protected?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2028495/834176)
- [Best to use Private methods or Protected methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/419844/834176)
- [Reasons to use private instead of protected for fields and methods](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4913025/834176)

#### My Question

Many people agree that protected methods should be used only when you have a reason to use them. How does a test-driven development model way into this? (Especially with regard to faking objects.) I have a friend who is a big fan of TDD and now BDD and is a C# developer, and he told me he hardly ever uses the `private` keyword. After he said that, I kept using it for fields but starting defaulting all of my methods to `protected`. Some people on StackOverflow also agree that `protected` should be used by default—could some of you please weigh in on this question? What is the best reason to use `protected` by default (since the threads above explain reasons not to)?

**Edit**: per Oded's comment, what about using `protected` by default and the Open-Closed Principle (a class should be open for extension and closed for modification)?

Comment: Apart from TDD, you may want to consider the [OCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle).

Comment: @Oded Thanks, that is definitely relevant.

Comment: Why would I want to make anything other than the least accessible option the default ? What's the upside of making everything protected/public? The tests just need to exercise the object via its public interface. The tests will help you with interface discovery.

Comment: I also think Unit Tests should cover the interface of your object, not the internals.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's what I consider a best practice, do with my developments and suggest to all of my clients:

1. Start with your test (or specification, if you're into BDD). Production classes and methods that you pull from your tests should be **public**.

   - Note: If you're developing in .NET, you may wish to consider using the **internal** keyword (and adding the **InternalsVisibleTo** assembly attribute to your production assembly, so that your test project can use the code) instead. Then you would make it **public** only if another **production assembly** depends on it.
2. Any method that you create as part of the *refactoring* phase of your TDD should be made **private**.
3. Make helper methods **protected** only when a derived production class needs them.
4. Any method created in the refactoring phase (now private or protected), that you need in **another production class** should be **extracted** to a helper class and made **public** (or **internal** in .NET, and any language that supports the concept).
5. If the helper class is needed in **another assembly**, then:

   - If the *other* assembly already depends on the helper class' assembly, make the helper class **public** (if it isn't already).
   - If the other assembly does **not** depend on the helper class' assembly, extract the helper class to a **helper assembly** (the best fit, or a new one) and make it **public**. Be sure to make the original assembly reference the new helper assembly, if it doesn't already.

This should pretty much cover all of your cases.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I would blog it sir, its solid advice. :)