# Should Members of a class that are object be public or not?

Tags: php, oop

I am currently developing a PHP application (v5.3.5 if it matters) and stumbled upon this question that I cannot seem to get a clear answer to while searching the internet.

So let's say I have a class `Body` that has two properties: `m_bAlive` and `m_oHead`. Head is an instance of a class that has setters and getters for it's properties (see example code). Should this object be public or private/protected as you'd normally declare it unless something else is necessary?

```
<?php
class Body {
    private $m_bAlive;
    private /*public*/ $m_oHead;
    //...
    //Getters and Setters here
}

class Head {
    private $m_bIsBald;
    //...
    //Getters and Setters here
}
```

By habit, I'd want to make `$m_oHead` `private`, but it feels as if it'd be overly complicated (and possibly slow?) to write `$oBody->getHead()->getIsBald()`. Maybe it just looks unusual to me because I don't come across this situation often, but I want to make sure.

Comment: Have you come from a Java background by any chance? The m_ looks like something I saw a lot of in Java users but not very often elsewhere. Personally I would always go for having a getter and private or protected attributes, that was I can add additional logic if required at a later date(IE: what happens if in future you decide to make the head lazy load, meaning it might not exist when the object is first loaded).

Comment: It seem a duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419844/best-to-use-private-methods-or-protected-methods

Comment: @scragar I personally didn't work with Java yet, but the head dev does and enforced this naming scheme.