# Hashing a password in ubuntu shell wihch will be compatible with nodejs bcrypt.hash

Tags: node.js, openssl, bcrypt

I have the following code to hash a password in nodejs

`await bcrypt.hash("my-password", 12)`

I would like to hash the same way in shell using  `openssl passwd` so it would be compatible with each-other. How is that possible?

Thanks

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/419855/310433 & https://www.ask-sheldon.com/create-a-bcrypt-hash-on-commandline/ <or> write a cli tool in node.js

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best to use Private methods or Protected methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419844/best-to-use-private-methods-or-protected-methods)